# Send and receive massive SMS with a PC by a mobile phone

Tags: android, desktop-computer, sms

How can I send and receive SMS using my PC connected to a mobile phone?
I need this for a SMS marketing campaign so I can send multiple SMS to many recipients and extract answers. For SMS service I would like to use a mobile phone (ex. Android).
I really need extract/import SMS and contacts feature.

Comment: If you can use a phone, it's not a _massive_ SMS campaign. I've built SMS routers that handled 1000 SM/second; a phone would melt at those volumes. You need a direct line to a SMSC (SMS service center at telco) for that.

Comment: For massive campaign I mean 500 sms per day, I want to use my flat contract with my mobile provider.

Comment: @Tobia - You are going to get into serious contract problems if you attempt to send 500 text messages using a normal phone contract depending your location in the world.  That sort of thing requires special contracts and special equipment otherwise you risk simply being blocked after being reported by customers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the SmushBox is for you http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/smush/smart-sms-texting-for-everyone-the-smushbox. It was discussed in Security Now episode 398: http://www.grc.com/sn/sn-398.txt

Comment: I can not understand how this box works, does it use gsm net to send sms?

Comment: @Tobia: it uses the TMobile network, which is multi-protocol. But if you couldn't figure that out yourself, you're probably going to need expert technical help.

Comment: That's how I interpret those links, yes. You have a contract with a mobile provider, receive a phone number, then use it to send SMS. But why not ask the makers?

Comment: @MSalters I don't think it's provider-specific. Leo and Steve mentioned T-Mobile as an example in the podcast.

Comment: @JanDoggen: See the last FAQ: "NON-USA PRICE? ... our service deal is with major mobile provider, T-Mobile USA"